# React, Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, key

I've encountered "Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop." error.
My user data is not dynamic so I use static id for unique key prop.

```
const App = () => {
  const meals = [
    {
      name: "Kimchi Fried Rice",
      info: "Delicious kimch and fresh veggies with rice",
      price: 10.99,
      id: 1,
    },
    {
      name: "Bibimbap",
      info: "Fresh veggies with spicy sauce ",
      price: 15.99,
      id: 2,
    },
    {
      name: "Ddeok bokki",
      info: "Chewy rice cake stirred with spicy sauce",
      price: 10,
      id: 3,
    },
    {
      name: "Son tofu",
      info: "The softest tofu soup ever ",
      price: 11.99,
      id: 4,
    },
  ];
  // console.log(meals.map((a) => a.name));
  return (
    <div>
      <Layout food={meals} />
    </div>
  );
};

const Layout = (props) => {
  return (
    <Card>
      <div className={classes.frame}>
        {props.food.map((menu) => (
          <ul>
            <li className={classes.name} key={menu.id}>
              {menu.name}
            </li>
            <li className={classes.info}>{menu.info}</li>
            <li className={classes.price}>{menu.price}$</li>
            <Button>+Add</Button>
          </ul>
        ))}
      </div>
    </Card>
  );
};
```

I initially made this code

```
        <li className={classes.name} key={menu.id}>
          {menu.name}
        </li>
        <li className={classes.info} key={menu.id}>
          {menu.info}
        </li>
        <li className={classes.price} key={menu.id}>
          {menu.price}$
        </li>
```

But this error -> Encountered two children with the same key, `1`. Keys should be unique so that components maintain their identity across updates. Non-unique keys may cause children to be duplicated and/or omitted — the behavior is unsupported and could change in a future version.
I tried to use Math.random.().toString() for a key but it just threw a same error.
Could anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The list in the error message refers to a list of items rendered by `Array.map()`. In your case, each `menu` item is a `ul` element, so the error message's "child in the list" refers to the `ul`. Move the key to the `ul`:

```
{props.food.map((menu) => (
  <ul key={menu.id}>
    <li className={classes.name}>
      {menu.name}
    </li>
    <li className={classes.info}>{menu.info}</li>
    <li className={classes.price}>{menu.price}$</li>
    <Button>+Add</Button>
  </ul>
))}
```

Comment: Oh no you're a genius. I was only thinking of "li" as a list but ul(unordered list) is also list! Thank you

Comment: The list refers to a list of rendered items, not an actual HTML list. Change the `ul` to a `div`, and you'll get the same error. The key should be on each rendered item, regardless of their HTML meaning.